# Using. np.isclose Function to compare two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframe with the same size and same variables.

```
df1 size: (50, 3) 
df2 size: (50, 3)
```

In my code, I'm using `np.isclose` function to return a boolean array where two arrays are element-wise equal within a tolerance as follows:

```
feature_1 = np.isclose(df1["SepalLengthCm"], df2["SepalLengthCm"], atol=10)

feature_2 = np.isclose(df1["SepalWidthCm"], df2["SepalWidthCm"], atol=20)

feature_3 = np.isclose(df1["PetalLengthCm"], df2["PetalLengthCm"], atol=30)
```

The code is working ok without any error.
But the issue for me is that I want to make this process more general and automatic. In other word, it should be working with any other datasets.

The important thing is that I dont want to specify the columns name in the code. So I want use `for` loop to automatically iterate over each column and doing the same thing.

Instead of having three codes (lines) for each column like `feature_1`  `feature_2`  `feature_3`, I want to write one code (line) to do the same job for any number of columns. Something like this:

```
feature = np.isclose(df1[columnn], df2[columnn], atol=i)
```

the parameter for `atol` should be also predefined in advance, for example `i = [10, 20, 30]`

Comment: So do you need `f = lambda col,atol: np.isclose(df1[col], df2[col], atol=atol)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a function containing the loop you want, and call it as a one-liner:

```
def compare_isclose(df1, df2, atol_list):
    feature_list = []
    for i, col in enumerate(df1.columns):
        feature_list.append(np.isclose(df1[col], df2[col], atol=atol_list[i]))
    feature_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(feature_list).T
    return feature_df
```

The function can be used this way:

```
atol_list = [10,20,30]
feature_df = compare_isclose(df1, df2, atol_list)
```

It only works under the assumption that the number of elements in atol_list equals the number of columns in the dataframe, and that the column names of the 2 dataframes are identical.

Comment: Great, it worked!! Just one more thing, how would we convert feature_list array to pd dataframe? The new dataframe should have three columns.

Comment: I edited the answer to return a dataframe instead of a list

Comment: Thanks. Finally, for `atol_list`, I want to take the values from another dataframe and put it in `atol_list`. The dataframe has a column named "tolerance" with three values. So I want to take these values and put in `atol_list`

Comment: atol_list = df['tolerance'].values.tolist()